# SQL Custom Sorting Bandwidth Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

**Beloved SO Cronies,**

I'm trying to custom sort bandwidth data using `ORDER BY` or any performance-focused solution likely involving a temp table.  I've scoured SO and Google and have only turned up parts of functions that I can use, so I've arrived at posting here as a final stop.

**Data (example)**

```
VALUE
---------
10 Kbps
5 Kbps
1 Mbps
10 Mbps
100 Mbps
10 Gbps
1 Gbps
```

**SQL fiddle** with the below.  Can you hear it playing in the background?

**[Bandwidth Sorting Start (SQL Fiddle)](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0655b/1)**

```
select * from Bandwidth
order by ( 
case
    when Value like '%kbps%' then 1
    when Value like '%mbps%' then 2
    when Value like '%gbps%' then 3
    else 4
end)
```

**My thinking is** splitting the string `Value` into a parameter and running a case on the metric type *(e.g. Kbps, Mbps)* then applying a multiplier to the parameter based on that and presenting that in a temp table that I can sort and return on an int-based sort without showing the column in the results!

Thanks in advance.  I tried to post on DBA StackExchange but existing work location presently blocks the login creation there.

Comment: Not totally sure what your proposed solution means but the problem you are facing is because your where predicate is nonSARGable. You have negated any indexing because you broke first normal by storing two values in a single intersection. You should have that broken into two columns, one for the value and one for unit of measure (or whatever). Then your query is painless and fast.

Comment: @SeanLange thanks but I'm dealing with a database design that already existed with end-users selecting data from a front-end SharePoint.  The way these tables currently exist are like lookups.  I'm aware of the best practice here and I absolutely agree.

Comment: You want something like this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0655b/18 ?

Comment: Badass, @Mihai.  At a glance this looks like it.  If you post as Answer i'll verify and check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a delimiter to separate the numbers and convert them to integer

```
order by

( 
case
    when Value like '%Kbps%' then 1
    when Value like '%Mbps%' then 2
    when Value like '%Gbps%' then 3
    else 4
end) ,
CONVERT(INT,SUBSTRING(Value, 0, CHARINDEX(' ', Value)))
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0655b/18)

Comment: Incredible.  It came down to just one line.  Thank you so much @Mihai.